# Using a php variable for validation in Laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-validation

I have this code that gets an object in a session and i put it in a certain variable. Then i wanted to use it in the laravel 4.2 'same' validation. So far here is the code i have

```
        session_start();
        $getsCapt = $_SESSION["captcha"];

        $rules = array(
            'st'           => 'required',
            'capt'         => 'required|numeric|same:$getsCapt'
        );
```

It is not doing anything. What i wanted to have is i'll compare the value i get from the session with the value i get from the textbox in my view named 'capt' but so far its not doing anything. any ideas to do this properly?

Comment: Use double quotes instead of single around the rules if you're using a variable. Single quotes is literally `$getsCapt` wheras double is the value of `$getsCapt`. See the [manual page for Strings for more info](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax)

Comment: Furthermore, doesn't the `same` rule match another field as opposed to a specific value? Try `in:$getsCapt` instead

Comment: Your view name is `capt` and you are checking for what??? what is the `capt` in the rules array ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, You are using `same` validator incorrectly.

`same` expects a form field name

Example:

`same:field_name`

Where, the given field must match the field under validation.

**You could register and use a Custom Validation Rule**

```
Validator::extend('captcha', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
     $captcha = \Session::get('captcha');
     return $value == $captcha;
});
```

So later you can do:

```
    //session_start(); - Please no need for this in Laravel
    //$getsCapt = $_SESSION["captcha"]; - Also remove this not necessary

    $rules = array(
        'st'           => 'required',
        'capt'         => 'required|numeric|captcha'
    );
```

NB: 
Use `Session::put` to save something to session e.g `\Session::put('something');`
There is also `Session::get` for retrieving value from session e.g `\Session::get('something');`

Please avoid using `$_SESSION` not Laravel way of doing things

[Edited] **Where to Register Custom Validation Rule?**

There are basically two ways you can register a custom validation rule in Laravel.

**1. Resolving from a closure:** 
If you are resolving through closure you can add it to : `app/start/global.php`

```
Validator::extend('captcha', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
     $captcha = \Session::get('captcha');
     return $value == $captcha;
});
```

**2. Resolving from a class**
This is the best and preferred way of extending custom validation rule as its more organised and easier to maintain.

**i.** Create your own validation class, `CustomValidator.php`, maybe in `app/validation` folder

```
<?php namespace App\Validation;

use Illuminate\Validation\Validator;
use Session;

class CustomValidator extends Validator{

    public function validateCaptcha($attribute, $value, $parameters)
    {
        $captcha = Session::get('captcha');
        return $value == $captcha;
    }
}
```

**NB:** Notice the prefix `validate` used in the method name, `validateCaptcha`

**ii.** Create a Service Provider that will resolve custom validator extension in `app/validation` folder

```
<?php namespace App\Validation;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class CustomValidationServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

public function register(){}

   public function boot()
   {
        $this->app->validator->resolver(function($translator, $data, $rules, $messages){
            return new CustomValidator($translator, $data, $rules, $messages);
       });
   }

}
```

**iii.** Then add `CustomValidationServiceProvider` under `app/config/app.php`  providers array:

```
'providers' => array(
  <!-- ... -->
  'App\Validation\CustomValidationServiceProvider'
),
```

**iv.** And add the custom error message in `app/lang/en/validation.php`

```
return array(
...
"captcha" => "Invalid :attribute entered.",
...
)
```

Comment: the custom validator is inside the controller?

Answer (score -2):

Change single quotes to double quotes

```
$rules = array(
    'st'   => 'required',
    'capt' => "required|numeric|same:$getsCapt"
);
```

Or simply concatenate the value

```
$rules = array(
    'st'   => 'required',
    'capt' => 'required|numeric|same:' . $getsCapt
);
```

Comment: Whilst this effectively interprets `$getsCapt` it doesn't actually answer the question.